# Show/Hide feature using HTML only

Tags: html, sharepoint

I want to create an element where it performs a show/hide functionality of text when a user clicks on a button. I've found a helpful page through this link: http://www.meadinkent.co.uk/expand_sections.htm

The only issue I have is that it uses javascript. As I want to place this into Sharepoint, what Sharepoint does is remove the `<script>` everytime it's submitted, so javascript I'm assuming can't be used.

I want to know if there is a way to perform the same functionality as displayed in the page but with HTML only?

Thank you

Comment: In SharePoint 2010 you can add `<script>` tags by saving the desired HTML/JavaScript into a text file in a document library, then by adding a content editor web part to a page and settings its "content link" property to the URL of the text file. SharePoint 2013 has a dedicated script editor web part, though its availability may depend upon your environment's configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add js by using Embed Code web part. Just go "Insert tab" and click "Embed Code". Then edit this and you will able to use js, css, html. So, you can use your helpful link.
[Embed code webpart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbyKC.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS to show/hide text. You can vist the following links, which may help you.
1) https://alexcican.com/post/hide-and-show-div/
2) [How to show/hide div on click with stricly HTML/CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26901466/how-to-show-hide-div-on-click-with-stricly-html-css)